# Mouseover/mouseenter not fired by browser on animated/moving element

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseover, jquery-events, mouseenter

If you have an element that has an animation to move it around, the `mouseover` and `mouseenter` events aren't fired unless the mouse is moved by the user. To demonstrate try the block of code below with jQuery.

If you put your mouse in front of the moving div so you're not moving the mouse when the div passes by then the `mouseover` isn't fired and the block doesn't stop.

In Firefox the `mouseover` event is fired without moving the mouse manually over the div, but only if you've moved the mouse at least once.

My question is there a workaround so an element moved under the mouse cursor will still have its `mouseover` event fired?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var move = 10,
        left = 0,
        width = 100;

    var stop = setInterval(function() {
        left += move;
        $('#mydiv').css('left', left);
        if (left < 0 || (left + width > parseInt($(window).width()))) 
            move = -1 * move;
    }, 10);

    $('#mydiv').mouseover(function() { clearInterval(stop); });
});
</script>
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: Black;">&#160</div>
```

I know the example is contrived, but it is just to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser bug.

The only workaround would be to track the global mouse coordinates in a `document`-level `mousemove` handler, then check during the animation whether the element covers those coordinates.